# Sharing constants between Django and angular

Tags: angularjs, json, django, constants, single-page-application

I'm working with a SPA web app with Django backend and Angular frontend. Sharing constants like enums (eg. Django model field choices, error codes/messages) has always been a struggle. Is there an easy way to handle them?

I was thinking about generating a JSON that contains every constant in the project, which is created on the backend (maybe during `collectstatic`), what can be loaded in a `<script>`tag during page load as a [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) object. The JSON resource name could look like `const.XXXX.json` where XXXX is the md5 sum of the file itself, so it can be cached and updated easily. The problem is that this would mean a lot of code change in Django.

Or maybe creating a repo which contains the shared constants, and bump it in both in the backend and frontend. But This would also mean a complete rewire. Maybe with this approach, I could make use of the IDE highlight both server and client side.

But both approaches take a relatively lot of effort and code change, so I thought I'll ask before jumping into it.

I've seen examples in php, Java, etc. But not for Django (and Angular).